# Question about basic properties of linear functions

Tags: functions

It is proveable that if
$$f(x)=\frac{f(x-k)+f(x+k)}{2}$$
and $f(0)=0 $ for all $x,k\in \mathbb{R} $

Then,$f(x)$ is linear

But my question is, if it is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but only for $some$ $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is it still proveable?

Comment: You also need $f$ continuous, I believe, in your first theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $f(x)=\sin x$.  Your relation is true for $k=2\pi$, but $f(x)$ is not identically $0$.

Comment: Does there exist more counter-examples that aren't k-periodical?

Comment: Sure, $f(x)=x+\sin x$.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, it was a question that was intriguing me.